# Turn on PC remotely

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop

I wonder how to turn on my PC from miles away?
I’m thinking to connect it w/ my smart plug and set it to AC Power Recovery.
But I wonder does it work?
1. Computer off
2. Off Smart Plug
3. On Smart Plug (AC Power recover)
4. Does the computer on?

Comment: Try searching with the keyword "wake on lan"

Comment: Voting to close because this belongs on [Super User.](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smart plugs are able to be turned off and on even from miles away. Including the proper AC Recovery settings you can indeed turn on your pc away from home.

Comment: Does the PC must be on sleep / hibernate? Can I fully turned it off?

Comment: I'm think that the PC would switch on though I don't know for sure.